# Remove all posible spaces in JSON message with Mule 4 dataweave

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I have a JSON message where I need to remove all format spaces keeping values untouched. This is required before running a hash function over the full payload so it needs to be precise.

I started with the `indent=false` in the Dataweave writer configuration but I got a space after each colon like this:

```
{"text": "number\": 1 | array\": [ | number\": 1","number": 1,"array": [1,"as",[],{}]}
```

Any suggested elegant solution to remove the spaces left before entering in the RegEx world? If not, any RegEx solution?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the spaces? It seems to be a valid JSON, and a valid parser should accept it.

Comment: Hi @aled. Yes, it is a valid JSON, but I need a binary match on what the server is expecting in this case so the hash calculated on the server-side is the same as the one I'm sending. Not the most clever implementation but I can't change the server-side.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532367/tail-recursion-in-dataweave

Comment: Hi @SalimKhan. The function on that post removes the spaces from the values, but I'm thinking that maybe I can convert that function into some custom JSON writer.

Answer (score 1):

I have got this solution following @SalimKhan (thanks for that!) suggested post. Basically I just wrote a full JSON custom writer on DataWeave.

```
fun jsonWrite(item) = item match {
    case is Array -> "[" ++ joinBy($ map jsonWrite($), ",") ++ "]"
    case is Object -> "{" ++ joinBy($ pluck ("\"" ++ $$ ++ "\":" ++ 
        ($ match {
            case is String -> "\"" ++ ($ replace "\"" with "\\\"") ++ "\""
            case is Object -> jsonWrite($)
            case is Array -> "[" ++ joinBy($ map jsonWrite($), ",") ++ "]"
            else -> $
        })),",") ++ "}"
    case is String -> "\"" ++ ($ replace "\"" with "\\\"") ++ "\""
    else -> $
}
```

Comment: I understand it solves your own problem, which requires a custom non-standard JSON representation, but I would not recommend to do this for other people. It is possible that this custom implementation might fail at border cases for other uses.

Comment: I agree. I would not spend a second if this was not needed having a tested OOTB DW writer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to remove all space from a json using below dw scripts.
The below one will give json in a stream with no indent, but there will be
space after each colon.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json indent=false
---
{
    name: "somename",
    city: "sg",
    profession: "tenchdigger"
}
```

The output of above script is converted to string and all spaces are removed using below script

```
%dw 2.0
var someSpaceJson = write(payload, "application/json", {"indent":false}) 
output application/java
---
someSpaceJson replace " " with ""
```

The end result is a json string with no space

```
"{"name":"somename","city":"sg","profession":"tenchdigger"}"
```